# Callback buttons trouble

Tags: python, django

Heey guys! I have some problem. I write bot for telegram with `telebot` and use for this mission `Django` . And now I was destroy my mind :(

this is my `views.py` code:

```
    i = 0
    keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for fish in Calculator.objects.all():
    keyboard.add(
        telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=fish.NameFishRus, callback_data='Lfish' + str(fish.IDfish)))
    bot.send_message(chat_id, mes, reply_markup=keyboard)
```

this is too in views:

```
 if callback_data.find('fish') != -1:
        fish_id = int(callback_data[5:])
        fish = Calculator.objects.get(IDfish=fish_id)
        user.fish = fish
        return HttpResponse('OK')
```

and my `models.py`:

```
class Calculator(models.Model):
    IDfish = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null=True, blank=True)
    NameFishRus = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank = True)
    NameFishLat = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank = True)
    NameFishEng  = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank = True)
```

This is callback button. Buuuuut, when i run my bot i see next :

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyvPD.png)

When i click in buttons, they don`t response me :(

Heelp pls!

P.S i can not attach tag `telebot`

Comment: please add more information to your question, by the way i love your profile picture 

Comment: @mohammedqudah ty bro ~*